# Angularjs - Dynamic data directive - create objects from strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, angularjs-directive

I am writing a directive that represents a table that gets populated with dynamic data. The dynamic data includes dynamic number of columns as well..

Here is my **plunker**:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pmCjQL39BWWowIAgj9hP?p=preview

**My directive code looks like this:**

```
app.directive("myTable", function() {
  return {
  restrict: "E",
  replace: true,
  scope: true,
  controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $http) {

  // Get Table Data
  $http.get('my-table.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.tableData = data;
    console.log($scope.tableData);

    $scope.tblKeys = [];

    for (key in $scope.tableHeader) {
      if ($scope.tableHeader.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $scope.tblKeys.push({key: key});
      }
    }
    console.log($scope.tblKeys);

  });
  },
  templateUrl: "template.html",
  compile: function(element, attrs) {

  return function(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.css = attrs.css;
    attrdata = attrs.values;

    //attrdata = "{'id':'ID Col', 'name':'Name Col', 'price':'Price Col', 'qty':'Quantity'}";

    convertdata = attrdata.replace(/'/g, '"');
    json = JSON.parse(convertdata);

    scope.tableHeader = json;
    console.log(scope.tableHeader);

  }; // return

  } // compile
  }
});
```

**And this is the directive template**

```
<table class="{{css}}" width="80%">

<thead>
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="title in tableHeader">
        {{title}}
    </th>
    <th>
        Cost
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tr ng-repeat="items in tableData">

    // >>>>>>>> THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP  <<<<<<<<

    <td> {{ items.id }}</td>
    <td> {{ items.name }}</td>
    <td> {{ items.price }}</td>
    <td> {{ items.qty }}</td>

    <td> {{ items.qty*items.price }}</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

---

**THE PROBLEM**

---

My directive is supposed to be able to set the columns data dynamically. I have been able to get the keys of values from the table object that the directive receives as an argument but I am unable to dynamically populate the table data from the tabeData objects using dynamic keys stored into scope.tblKeys

In my template these 4 lines where I would like to avoid using id,name,price and qty and instead get that data somehow from scope.tblKeys

```
    <td> {{ items.id }}</td>
    <td> {{ items.name }}</td>
    <td> {{ items.price }}</td>
    <td> {{ items.qty }}</td>
```

Something to the tune of

```
<tr ng-repeat="items in tableData">

    <td ng-repeat="key in tblKeys">  {{ items.key }}</td>

    <td> {{ items.qty*items.price }}</td>
</tr>
```

I am not sure how to make this happen `{{ items.key }}` and I am writing this part to illustrate what I need

```
<td ng-repeat="key in tblKeys">  {{ items.key }}</td>
```

I suppose I could use angular $parse but I am not sure how to approach this.

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that what you're storing as `key` has this structure: `{"key":"id"}`, so when you do `{{ items.key }}`, there's no property called key on this items object.

You want `{{ items[key.key] }}` if you intend to display the value of `items.id`.

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/chXJaNnu09NEdMIyUxi5?p=preview)

edit: or you could probably get away with pushing only the string onto `scope.tblKeys`:

```
$scope.tblKeys.push(key);
```

And accessing it in your directive with:

```
{{ items[key] }}
```

Comment: No problem. It's a really cool idea. A few years ago, I had to create a dynamically-generated table on the server side using C# and Linq-to-sql. It was a *lot* more code than what you have. ;)

Comment: In fact, I'm going to link your implementation to a guy I worked with on that project. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :) And thanks again! Don't you just love ng,, so little code ::)